# How to Reduce process time in process of encrytion and sending to server and fetching then decryption the Data?

Tags: android

I was trying to figure out How to Reduce process time in process of encryption the data and sending to server and fetching from server then decrypting the Data?

I am trying to do this in Android but I am thinking if the above thing could be done

Can somebody help me in this?